# Authentication with password and user to api through fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I have the following setup
Fastapi <-> client Class <-> API

The Fastapi is intended to fetch (and later also post) data in the API through the client.
The client must authenticate in the API and then do the usual CRUD functions.
The API gives you information depending on your requests.

The client class must receive the user and password as first step to auth in the API. How can I do this with the main of the fastapi if I don't want to have the user and pw fields in all possible endpoints?

Comment: How do you expect the client to include user/password? If the client includes them in every request, you can abstract it away with `api_client: ApiClient = Depends(get_api_client)`, where `get_api_client` is `get_api_client(x_user = Header(), x_password = Header()): .. create api client` for example (given that you have `X-User` and `X-Password` as http headers for communicating a username/password (You also want to use Annotated here, but I left that out to make the example more succinct). This is what `Depends` is for, so that you can abstract away what it means "to get a service client"

Comment: I think you should start from reading FastAPI documentation. This topic is explained well in the 'security' section: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/